# Using debug module with ansible-console

Tags: ansible

I am trying to understand how to use the `debug` module with `ansible-console`.
I start `ansible-console` like this:

```
bash-3.2$ ansible-console -i ,localhost --connection=local
```

Then I load some facts from my `/etc/ansible/facts.d` like so:

```
red@all (1)[f:5]$ setup
...
```

Then I output the value of my fact like so:

```
red@all (1)[f:5]$ shell echo "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_local.decomm.list1[3] }}"
```

which outputs:

```
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
XXXX
```

But when I try to use the `debug` module like this:

```
red@all (1)[f:5]$ debug msg "{{ ansible_facts.ansible_local.decomm.list1[3] }}"
```

I get this unexpected output:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

Why didn't I get this output?

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "XXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `=`. `shell` accepts a freeform string that it executes, while most modules expect structured parameters. "Hello world!" is the result of the `debug` action with no parameters.

```
red@all (1)[f:5]$ debug msg="{{ ansible_facts.ansible_local.decomm.list1[3] }}"
```